# How to fix IMAP mailbox separator in Mail.app after server changed its internal separator from "." to "/"?

Tags: mail.app, imap

I've been using Mail.app for years with my employer's mailserver without problems. Recently, the mailservers were upgraded to a new system and the internal mailbox separator went from "." to "/".

For example, on the server, I have a mailbox named "2020" inside the mailbox "Sent". It was called `Sent.2020`, on the new server, it's named `Sent/2020`.

However, using Mail.app connexion doctor, I can see that Mail.app is still trying to access `Sent.2020` :

```
WROTE Apr 14 17:38:30.996 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:mailserver.my.org -- port:993 -- socket:0x60000235c8a0 -- thread:0x600001fb7280
6.19 SELECT Sent.2020 (CONDSTORE)

READ Apr 14 17:38:31.010 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:mailserver.my.org -- port:993 -- socket:0x60000235c8a0 -- thread:0x600001fb7280
6.19 NO SELECT failed
```

Similarly creating a submailbox results in the creation of a nonsub mailbox. let's say I want to create a mailbox named "lastweek" in mailbox "Sent", Mail.app will try to create "Sent.lastweek", while it should create "Sent/lastweek". In this case a mailbox is created, but Mail.app does not expect this mailbox, and it is a toplevel mailbox, not a submailbox of the Sent mailbox.

I tried to restart Mail.app, to reconstruct the main mailbox, but this did not produce any change.
I'd rather not delete and recreate the whole mailserver in Mail.app.

How can I explain to Mail.app that the internal mailbox separator has gone from "." to "/" ?

**Edit**

I know the new separator is a "/" because I asked the server with the `list` command and the list answer indicates a "/" as the separator :

```
1.0 list "" "%"
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "Archives"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Drafts) "/" "Drafts"
etc...
```

Comment: @Tetsujin, abosolutely not. The IMAP separator can be a "/". The best way to know what separator is employed by a given server is to ask the server itself, as stated in RFC 3501.See my edit in the question as I can't post code in a comment.

Comment: You may have to re-add the account to Mail. Is there a reason you don't want to do this? I do it frequently and it just takes a few minutes to re-sync.

Comment: Well, I'll have to do that on a few tens of macs, mine and others'. So, it will take time. Also, if I delete and re-add the account, I'm afraid I'll loose some settings or infos. I think of the signatures, the email references in calendar, the learnt spam, the rules. And probably some other things I don't think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This new answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441341) points to

`~/Library/Mail/V8/<account identifier>/.mboxCache.plist`

where the separator is cached (at the end). Presumably you could just edit that file.

Comment: Yes it works. The same file exists in V9. I also tried to remove the file. it also works, Mail.app recreates it with the correct content.